# Should we move this to Software Rec site, close it or leave it as is?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is a very popular question on the site (approx 1,600 views) but is clearly asking for a  software recommendation:
https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/project-management-software-for-a-small-team-with-shifting-priorities

Should we move it, close it or leave it on the site for its popularity?

Comment: Looks like it was closed by 5 of our community members... the community hath spoken and *status-completed*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While these sorts of questions are now considered off-topic on PMSE, they weren't always. In addition, even if it were appropriate for the other site (which is debatable), migrating it will remove rep from PMSE users, and possibly unfairly skew rep on the receiving site.

My personal recommendation is to close it as software recommendation (per our current guidelines) but to leave it here on PMSE for posterity. That preserves the information in the answers, preserves the rep of the users who answered it, but still makes it clear that this sort of question is now out of scope per our current guidelines.

Comment: I like the idea of closing it but keeping it on the site. @jmort253, what do you think?

Comment: Closing sounds like the right approach to me. That will keep it from getting bumped back to the top, especially if it would only attract spam or noise.

Comment: As the OP of the question in question, I approve this plan.

Answer (score 2):

The [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site is an early public beta that's much different from most Stack Exchange sites. They've taken on a topic that most Stack Exchange communities aren't willing to engage, and they created [a rigid set of guidelines regarding what to ask and how questions should be answered](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules). In short, they've taken recommendation questions, added more details and constraints to them, and turned the answers into a product knowledge-base for people looking for information to help them make informed decisions.

Due to the nature of the topic, that community asks that we -- and all other Stack Exchange sites -- [refrain from migrating any content to their site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/762/772).

Additionally, Stack Exchange [disabled migrations on questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/155826). So at this point, we're just stuck with these questions. :)

As for what to do with such questions, the main reason we added them to the do not ask list is because they attract such horrid answers. But the example you cite actually *appears* pretty decent compared to other recommendation posts. If one of us were to edit it a bit, convert some of it to bullet-points/formatted lists to make it easier to read, and overall make it look like something we're proud to have on our site, that would allow us to re-evaluate it and determine it's future, whether that be leaving it open or marking it as off-topic. Cleaning it up would definitely help us see if there is any real value there or if it's just noise. Hope this helps!